# C# dataset clear method

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#. I want to create a windows form with a combobox and a dataGridView. I fill the dataGridView based on the selected value from the combobox. So far so good. But when I change the value of the combobox, and try to reload the dataGridView's contents like so:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null) 
    { 
        if (ds.Tables.Contains("Leagues"))
        { 
            ds.Tables["Leagues"].Clear(); // <-- error happens here 
        }
        leagues_adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        main.InsertCommand.Parameters[0].Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue; 
        leagues_adapter.Fill(ds, "Leagues"); 
    } 
}
```

When `myDataSet.Tables["myTable"].Clear()` is called, I get on a DataGridView Default Error Dialog the following:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 0 does not have a value
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ConcurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32
>   index) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32
>   rowIndex). To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

I also have an OK button.

This happens only when I want to change the contents of the combobox from a certain value to some other value. 
However, if I hit the OK button lots of times, I see that with every hit, an element from a row and a column is removed one by one, and when I consume all the elements with the OK button, I finally get what I wanted: the dataGridView with the new data in it. Please help me, any answer is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: here is the code for my problem:

Comment: sorry for the formatting, I'm new to stackoverflow also

Comment: How do you fill the DataGridView?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  We edit our questions here to add additional information (such as code).  You can edit your question by clicking the *edit* link on the left, just under your question.

Comment: I fill my dataSet (which is a strongly typed dataSet),then I the dataGtidView.DataSet to one of these tables in the dataSet. Then I try to reload the dataGridView based on the value of the combobox, the code for that is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear the binding and re-set it after reloading the data:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.DataSource = null;

    // Reload data with the code in your question.

    dataGridView.DataSource = // same code as you are using right 
                              // now for setting the binding
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I understand now why it didn't work in it's previous form. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot clear the dataTable if this is used as a data source of dataGridView.

Comment: Could You explain it a bit more detailed, please?